# Group_by and find intersect between groups tidyverse

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, intersect

I'm trying to `group_by` and find the `intersect` between the groups defined by `group_by` using `tidyverse`.

example data:

`data = tibble(feature = paste0("Group_", sample(1:800, 1000, replace = T)),classifier = paste0("Classifier_", sample(1:3, 1000, replace = T)))`

the data looks like this:

```
  # A tibble: 1,000 x 2
   feature   classifier  
   <chr>     <chr>       
 1 Group_629 Classifier_2
 2 Group_549 Classifier_1
 3 Group_565 Classifier_1
 4 Group_584 Classifier_2
 5 Group_181 Classifier_2
 6 Group_359 Classifier_3
 7 Group_135 Classifier_1
 8 Group_676 Classifier_3
 9 Group_731 Classifier_1
10 Group_694 Classifier_2
# … with 990 more rows
```

I'm trying to `group_by(classifier)` and find the `intersect()` between all of the groups.

Code:

```
data = tibble(feature = paste0("Group_", sample(1:800, 1000, replace = T)),
              classifier = paste0("Classifier_", sample(1:3, 1000, replace = T))) %>% group_by(classifier) %>%
              mutate(intersect = intersect(feature))
```

produces this error:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `intersect`.
x argument "y" is missing, with no default
ℹ Input `intersect` is `intersect(feature)`.
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: classifier = "Classifier_1".
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Because I am not providing 2 arguments to `intersect`.

Does anyone have a solution for this? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

`group_by` is meant for group-wise computations on a dataframe. To get a list of the `feature`s which your groups have in common you could split your data by `classifier` and use `semi_join`:

```r
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)

data <- tibble(feature = paste0("Group_", sample(1:800, 1000, replace = T)),
              classifier = paste0("Classifier_", sample(1:3, 1000, replace = T)))

data_split <- data %>% 
  split(.$classifier)

data_split$Classifier_1 %>% 
  semi_join(data_split$Classifier_2, by = "feature") %>% 
  semi_join(data_split$Classifier_3, by = "feature") %>% 
  pull(feature)
#>  [1] "Group_374" "Group_141" "Group_409" "Group_291" "Group_648" "Group_696"
#>  [7] "Group_55"  "Group_447" "Group_422" "Group_292" "Group_39"  "Group_358"
#> [13] "Group_177" "Group_373" "Group_464" "Group_348" "Group_468" "Group_8"  
#> [19] "Group_463" "Group_712" "Group_48"  "Group_665" "Group_229" "Group_209"
#> [25] "Group_271" "Group_229" "Group_8"   "Group_55"  "Group_55"  "Group_709"
#> [31] "Group_665" "Group_217" "Group_278" "Group_280" "Group_355" "Group_348"
#> [37] "Group_703" "Group_39"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!
I solved it with:

`data = tibble(feature = paste0("Group_", sample(1:800, 1000, replace = T)), classifier = paste0("Classifier_", sample(1:3, 1000, replace = T))) %>% group_by(classifier) %>% nest() %>% ungroup() %>% summarise(intersect_feat = map(1:n_distinct(.$classifier), function(x).$data[[x]]$feature) %>% reduce(intersect))`